# Wipe out all data in a scheme, leave structure intact

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, testing

We're going to be going through a period of testing on a product soon.  This product is a web application with a SQL Server 2008R2 backend.

Our database has several schemas within it (Customer, DataEntry, and a few others).

I have found ways to [wipe all data in a database](http://www.mikemarks.net/blog/delete-all-data-from-a-database/) without breaking referential integrity or the data structures, which is close to what we're looking to do.  The problem I'm finding is that we actually need a bunch of the data from some of the tables.  Essentially, we only want to wipe the Customers schema.

We have a script written which will load in the test data for customers, but is there a way to change the techniques in my linked article to target only a specific schema?  Is there a better way to clear all data in a schema?

Answer (score 1):

A common scenario for me as well. I usually write what I call a reset script, deleting all data form the target tables in the order necessary to prevent referential errors, and then reseed the primary keys.

```
DELETE FROM < table 1 >
DELETE FROM < table 2 >
... etc ...    
DBCC CHECKIDENT (< table 1 >, RESEED, 0)
DBCC CHECKIDENT (< table 2 >, RESEED, 0)
... etc ...
```

EDIT

To more fully answer the original question. to leave data in specific tables you would need to modify the block of code that does the deleting / truncating, and also modify the code that reseeds the idents in a similar way.

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable '
    IF object_id(''?'') != < table name > AND object_id(''?'') != < table name > AND ... etc ...
    BEGIN
        IF OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id(''?''), ''TableHasForeignRef'') = 1
            DELETE FROM ?
        ELSE
            TRUNCATE TABLE ?
    END
'
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the @schemaID to the name of the schema you wish to blow away and it should do the rest. If you end up with a FK dependency loop it will break and tell you what to do...

```
Declare @schemaID Nvarchar(256)
Set     @schemaID = 'Schema' -- Set this to the name of the schema you wish to blow away

If      Object_ID('tempdb..#tables') Is Not Null Drop Table #tables
Create  Table #tables (tID Int, SchemaName Nvarchar(256), TableName Nvarchar(256))

Insert  #tables
Select  Row_Number() Over (Order By s.name, so.name), s.name, so.name
From    sysobjects so
Join    sys.schemas s
        On  so.uid = s.schema_id
Where   so.xtype = 'u'
And     s.name = @schemaID

Declare @SQL Nvarchar(Max),
        @schema Nvarchar(256),
        @table Nvarchar(256),
        @iter Int = 1,
        @loopCatch Int = 0

While   Exists (Select  1
                From    #tables)
Begin
        Select  @schema = SchemaName,
                @table = TableName
        From    #tables
        Where   tID = @iter

        If      Exists (Select  1
                        From    sysobjects o
                        Join    sys.schemas s1
                                On  o.uid = s1.schema_id
                        Join    sysforeignkeys fk
                                On  o.id = fk.rkeyid
                        Join    sysobjects o2
                                On  fk.fkeyid = o2.id
                        Join    sys.schemas s2
                                On  o2.uid = s2.schema_id
                        Join    #tables t
                                On  o2.name = t.TableName Collate Database_Default
                                And s2.name = t.SchemaName Collate Database_Default
                        Where   o.name = @table
                        And     s1.name = @schema)
        Begin
                Update  t
                Set     tID = (Select Max(tID) From #tables) + 1
                From    #tables t
                Where   tableName = @table
                And     schemaName = @schema

                Set     @iter = @iter + 1
        End
        Else
        Begin
                Set     @Sql = 'Truncate Table [' + @schema + '].[' + @table + ']'

                Begin   Try
                        Exec    sp_executeSQL @SQL;

                        Delete  t
                        From    #tables t
                        Where   tableName = @table
                        And     schemaName = @schema

                        Set     @iter = @iter + 1
                End     Try
                Begin   Catch
                        Print @SQL

                        Update  t
                        Set     tID = (Select Max(tID) From #tables) + 1
                        From    #tables t
                        Where   tableName = @table
                        And     schemaName = @schema

                        Set     @iter = @iter + 1
                        Set     @loopCatch = @loopCatch + 1;

                        If      @loopCatch > 5
                        Begin
                                Select  'WARNING: Endless FK redundancy loop. Drop the constraints and these tables, truncate and reapply constraints manually'
                                Union   All
                                Select  '[' + SchemaName + '].[' + TableName + ']'
                                From    #tables;                

                                Break;
                        End                     
                End     Catch
        End
End
```

Answer (score 1):

This is parameterized on database and schema. If no schema is supplied, it will clear all data in the specified database.

Handles tables with foreign key references appropriately by disabling constraints. If the procedure fails, which it shouldn't normally do, ensure that you run it successfully after fixing the cause of the problem, which should ensure constraint checking goes back to normal.

This will not handle foreign key references correctly if you have foreign keys between schemas, however, it could be fairly easily amended to handle this.

```
create procedure [removeData] (@database_name sysname, @schema_name sysname = null)
as
    set nocount on

    create table #tables (
        TableName varchar(900) not null primary key,
        HasFKRef bit not null
    );

    declare @sql nvarchar(4000),
            @table_name varchar(900);

    if (db_id(@database_name) is null)
        raiserror ('You must at least specify the database name', 16, 1);

    set @sql = 'select ''['' + TABLE_CATALOG + ''].['' + TABLE_SCHEMA + ''].['' + TABLE_NAME + '']'' as TableName, (case when exists(select * from [' + @database_name + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc inner join [' + @database_name + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc on rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = tc.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG and rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = tc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA and rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME where tc.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME) then 1 else 0 end) as HasFKRef
        from [' + @database_name + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
        where TABLE_TYPE = ''BASE TABLE'' and TABLE_SCHEMA = isnull(@schema_name, TABLE_SCHEMA)';

    insert into #tables
        exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@schema_name sysname', @schema_name;

    declare @curse cursor 
    set @curse = cursor fast_forward for
    select sql from (
        select 'alter table ' + TableName + ' nocheck constraint all' as sql, 1 as sort
        from #tables
        union all
        select 'truncate table ' + TableName, 2 as sort
        from #tables
        where HasFKRef = 0
        union all
        select 'delete from ' + TableName, 3 as sort
        from #tables
        where HasFKRef = 1
        union all
        select 'alter table ' + TableName + ' with check check constraint all', 4 as sort
        from #tables
    ) t
    order by sort, sql

    open @curse

    fetch next from @curse into @sql

    while (@@fetch_status = 0)
    begin
        exec (@sql)

        fetch next from @curse into @sql
    end

    close @curse
GO
```